# Setting up nginx on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I've just setup a VPS running Ubuntu server 10.10 as a test environment to run with nginx. This far i've ran `apt-get install nginx php5 php5-cgi` and accessed the IP of the VPS with a browser which outputs **It works**, so it should be ready to run. Never having worked with nginx in the past, I have no idea on what to do next.

How should I config my nginx install to run properly as a staging server in my LAN?
Apparently, there's multiple configs for nginx including `sites-default` and `nginx-default` making me really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exceptional Linode Library has an article on how to install a LEMP stack on Ubuntu 10.10: http://library.linode.com/lemp-guides/ubuntu-10.10-maverick/

Answer (score 2):

nginx works very similarly to how Apache works on Debian systems. There are two folders inside of /etc/nginix

```
/etc/nginx
```

The two folders are sites-enabled and sites-available. The way you make it work is to write a  [Virtual host config](http://wiki.nginx.org/VirtualHostExample)

inside of sites-available, then make a symbolic link using ln -s to sites-enabled, once this is done you can restart nginix and that virutal host config will be loaded. The server will only read configs that are in sites-enabled. You can use this for hosting multiple different virtual hosts however if you just want to run a single website leave the default virtual host enabled and work with that.

The default config should look something like:

```
server {
    listen   80 default;
    server_name  localhost;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    location / {
            root   /var/www/nginx-default;
            index  index.html index.htm;
    }
```

Which will be in a file called /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.

All that config is doing is telling nginix to listen on port 80, write to the access log defined there.Its document root is in /var/www/nginx-default.

Lets say you put some html file in /var/www/nginx-default/foo.html, you would be able to access that file through going to your yourip/foo.html

[Here is a good guide on how to setup nginx with PHP](http://www.howtoforge.com/installing-php-5.3-nginx-and-php-fpm-on-ubuntu-debian)